# FancyBox Images Aren't Loading Correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, masonry

I'm using a combination of the Masonry and Fancybox plugins to create a photo gallery, but the images loaded by FancyBox aren't displaying correctly. They are forced to the right side of the screen, and are taking too much space. I should also note that both the white border and the arrow buttons aren't appearing, and that you can't close the images by clicking outside of them. Here is a screenshot of my page.

[image]

The gallery is on the left, and the loaded image is forced to the right side of the screen. It's also considerably larger than it should be. Here's the code I'm using.

Links

```
<link href="css/styles_desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
div#gallery {
    width: 990px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.item {
    width: 330px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

jQuery

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            $('#gallery').masonry({
                columnWidth: 330, itemSelector: '.item'
            }).imagesLoaded(function () {
                $("#gallery").masonry('reload');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="other/edits/DSC00232.jpg">
        <img class="item" src="other/edits/DSC00232.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="other/edits/DSC00274.jpg">
        <img class="item" src="other/edits/DSC00274.jpg"> 
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="other/edits/DSC00257.jpg">
        <img class="item" src="other/edits/DSC00257.jpg"> 
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="other/edits/DSC00293.jpg">
        <img class="item" src="other/edits/DSC00293.jpg"> 
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="other/edits/DSC00235.jpg">
        <img class="item" src="other/edits/DSC00235.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="other/edits/DSC00236.jpg">
        <img class="item" src="other/edits/DSC00236.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I can try to make one, but I'm having trouble getting the images to work on it.

Comment: Here's a link to the site, I couldn't get the fiddle to work properly.

http://jordanwebdesign.x10host.com/renovation/gallery.html

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: The fancybox.css not applied in site.

Comment: Please make sure fancybox.css working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery.fancybox.css file not loaded properly in your site. Please  copy the all style from jquery.fancybox.css and insert into style.descktop.css file. It will works fine. Seems It is an issue.

Comment: Thanks. i just went through and redid the link, and it immediately works.